# GetVerifiedStatus with Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, paypal

Is there any example of using GetVerifiedStatus with Classic ASP?
Im downloaded the examples from Paypal but there is not any about GetVerifiedStatus.

Tks for help

Comment: Paypal guys, can you provide some example about it?

Answer (score 2):

All of the Classic ASP examples that we have would be found at https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index towards the bottom of the page.  These SDK's may not include every example, however for the ones that are not included you could simply modify one of the other examples.  It would just be a matter of passing over different parameters and values.  You should be able to use the developer guides to see which variables are required, and what you can expect back in the response.

Comment: Can you tell me witch of these examples can I use for the GetVerifiedStatus?

Tks

Comment: I thought there use to be an example on that page that was in Classic ASP for Adaptive Payments.  This would be the one that you would want to use, however searching the page I am only seeing ASP.NET.  I will search and see if I can find a copy of the code, if we had it.  Othewise, would have to use https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/getverifiedstatus-api-operation as a reference and build the code for the API call.